# Revel: pass template var to url

Tags: templates, variables, go, revel

I want to understand how `url` helper works.
For example, in my template I have:

```
<a href="{{url "Pages.IndexPages" ???}}">my super url</a>
```

and in controller:

```
func (c Pages) IndexPages() revel.Result {
    ...
}
```

I need url like

```
http://localhost:9000/pages?page=1
```

I don't want to write:

```
func (c Pages) IndexPages(page int) revel.Result {
```

because I want to check if the controller contains the param `page`.
How to add my template var to `c.Params.Query` with the `url` helper?

Comment: For future reference, you may have better luck with Revel-specific questions on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/revel-framework

Answer (score 1):

[Revel url helper code in template.go](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/c5893f222a8983e12aaac6ffaac0362ddcc56087/template.go#L456)

```
// Return a url capable of invoking a given controller method:
// "Application.ShowApp 123" => "/app/123"
func ReverseUrl(args ...interface{}) (template.URL, error) {
```

We need to update the manual with information about this template function, but you can see in the link and code above how it's intended to be used. You pass it a controller and action with parameters and it creates a `template.URL` object with the matching route.

It seems you're not interested in how the `url` helper works (though that's what you asked). You want to know how to pass the `page` variable to the template? In your controller you need to pass `page` via `c.RenderArgs["page"] = page`. Then you can reference it in your template: `<a href="{{url "Pages.IndexPages" .page}}">my super url</a>` [Revel Template Doc](http://revel.github.io/manual/templates.html).

As you noted, you can manually get the value for `page` with `page := c.Params.Query.Get("page")` if you don't want to use the parameter binding feature.

Comment: and how my controller supposed to looks like? please, re-read my question about `page` parameter

Comment: Updated. Does that answer all of your questions?

Comment: you didn't understand me again =) `<a href="/pages/indexpages?page={{.page}}">my super url</a>`, how to do this with `Revel`? In my controller I don't want to write `func (c Pages) IndexPages(page int) revel.Result {`

Comment: the way is to access my `page` by `c.Params.Query.Get("page")`, I think =\

Comment: Oh, yes, you found it. That's how you can manually get the value of the `page` variable passed in the URL. Sorry for the misunderstanding.